# Разве эта часть образует придаточную часть?

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Я, когда ехал в машине, задумался над одним предложением.

«Я не понимаю, в чём смысл». Как я понял, в данном случае у нас придаточная изъяснительная (союз ЧТО в предложном падеже). Не прав — поправьте меня. Я в этом ещё профан. Только мне интересно кое-что другое. Грамматическая часть главного предложения (Я не понимаю), а вот про второе предложение я ничего не могу сказать. Во-первых, я полагаю, что в данном случае мы имеем придаточную односоставную часть (номинанативную).

В предложении «Я не понимаю, в чём заключается смысл» всё выражено гораздо понятнее. В данном случае и главное, и зависимое предложение имеет вид двусоставного предложения.

Помогите-ка решить данный вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«Я не понимаю, в чём смысл». Всё Вы, Тагир,понимаете правильно. Сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным. Я не понимаю -главное предложение, двусоставное ( кто? -я. Что делаю? - не понимаю) чего?-далее следует изъяснение (пояснение).

Придаточное предложение - неполное двусоставное с пропуском простого глагольного сказуемого (заключается,состоит - простое глагольное сказуемое,а  не составное именное и не нулевая связка).Его называют ещё эллиптическим (эллипсис), т.е. сказуемого нет, но смысл понятен и без него,оно не нужно. В чём - это никакая не именная часть сказуемого, это обстоятельство со значением дополнения (смысл где? в чём?), союзное слово, выраженное местоимением. О наличии глагола (подразумевании его)как раз и говорит наличие обстоятельства, потому что оно относится только к сказуемому.

Придаточная часть может присоединяться к главной с помощью союза или союзного слова. Что может быть союзом - Я знаю, что он ушёл.(что не является членом предложения, потому что выражено служебной частью речи - союзом) .И союзным словом, являющимся членом предложения. Я знаю, что ему требуется. Я знаю, о чём он говорит.

Comment: А о нулевой связке в школе говорят в связи с составным именным сказуемым: Я ученик. Я ( есть кто?) я (есть)ученик. Есть - нулевая глагольная связка, посмотрите в учебнике за 8 класс, если он есть. Нулевая, потому что она проявляется в прошедшем и будущем времени:Я был учеником. Я буду учеником.

Comment: Сейчас я не занимаюсь, к сожалению. Когда начну заниматься, постараюсь посмотреть.

Comment: Людмиле. "В чем смысл.В чем заключается смысл. Что является смыслом". - Разве это не одно и то же? Почему же в этих конструкциях нельзя видеть составные именные сказуемые?

Comment: Значение близкое, но синтаксис-то разный.

Comment: В чем смысл.-неполное двусоставное.В чем заключается смысл.-полное двусоставное, где простое глагольное сказ. заключается. Это не связка, это полноправный глагол. Что является смыслом- полное двусоставное, но совсем другое предложение.Является - глаг.связка в сост.именном сказуемом. Это разные предложения,а смысл одинаковый, так мы одну и ту же мысль можем выразить совершенно разными предложениями с совершенно разной лексикой. Вы лексику изменили - другое предложение. Одно дело пропустить - другое - изменить форму слова(смысл -является смыслом).

Answer (score 2):

Tagirix,Вы пишете, что Вам более понятна придаточная часть в виде "в чём заключается смысл". Думаю, здесь ключ к ответу. Подлежащее - "смысл", это несомненно, а вот со сказуемым посложнее. Вы "почувствовали" подразумеваемое сказуемое "заключается", но это только часть сказуемого, глагол-связка, а главная, именная часть выражена в данном случае местоимением "в чем". Эту фразу можно передать иначе: "ЧТО (местоимение) есть смысл". Глаголы "заключается, называется, кажется и т.п." называют глаголами со стёртым лексическим значением, и они обычно выступают в роли глагола-связки в составном именном сказуемом.

Comment: А про первое предложение Вы ничто не сказали. Почему?

Comment: О предложении "я не понимаю"? Но Вы ведь сами ответили, что это нераспространенное предложение, состоящее только из грамматической основы "я не понимаю"

Comment: В смысле? Меня интересует придаточные часть в предложении «Я не понимаю, в чём смысл».

Comment: Прочтите, пожалуйста, мой основной ответ Он как раз и посвящен придаточной части "в чем смысл"

Comment: Я не понимаю Вас, к сожалению.

Comment: Простите, как умею. Может, кто-нибудь объяснит более понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Вторая часть сложного  предложения двусоставное предложение с нулевой связкой " заключается".

Comment: Да какая нулевая связка? О таком в школе вообще говорят?

Comment: Со школьной программой я не знаком. Связку я указал - " заключается".

Comment: Серж, со связками  все очень строго. Сказуемое обозначает признак, приписываемый подлежащему, этот признак может выражаться сущ., прил. и др. В этом случае необходима связка, при этом существует три вида связок: а) незнаментельная связка БЫТЬ: "Смысл жизни есть сама жизнь. Или: "Смысл жизни - это сама жизнь" (здесь нулевая связка).б) Полузнаменательная связка: "Сама жизнь является  смыслом". в) Знаменательная связка со значением движения  или состояния: "Он пришел усталым, он спал одетым". В этих примерах мы как бы имеем осложненную по смыслу связку "быть". А  "заключается" - это не связка.

Comment: Вопрос № 276734  
Глагол "заключается" может быть связкой или нет ? Честно говоря , в Интернете ничего не нашел. Спасибо! 
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Глагол заключается может выступать как синоним связочного глагола быть.

Так что, в данном случае, это все же глагол связка, а не простое глагольное сказуемое.

Comment: И ответ от Граммы.ру. 
 В предложении  "Я не понимаю, в чем вопрос'' придаточную часть можно квалифицировать как двусоставное предложение с составным именным сказуемым, включающим нулевую связку.

Comment: Грамоте.ру иногда свойственно ошибаться. Возьмем, например, учебник Розенталя для вузов "Современный русский язык". Там на двух страницах изложены виды связок, на девяти - виды  именной части. Но нет там связки "заключается", и нет предложной формы в качестве имени.

Comment: Далее:"является предметом" и "заключается в предмете" - это разные понятия. Вот, к примеру, счастье. Некоторые считают, что счастье в борьбе, то есть оно сопутствует людям с борцовскими качествами в качестве морального удовлетворения от одержанных побед. Но можно ли думать, что счастье - это борьба? Сама потасовка, как мне кажется, счастья ее участникам  не прибавляет.

Comment: София, заметьте ,однако, что один и тот же ответ дали и Грамма.ру и Грамота.ру. Неужели вы не доверяете им?

Comment: Я им доверяю, когда наши мнения совпадают. В противном случае приходится искать третейского судью - и тогда кого же, если не Розенталя.